# Put a query into a foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use the returned shortest path between each node and the root (Main topic classification) to build my graph. I use the following query

```
 MATCH ()-[:SUBJECT]->(c:Category)
 UNWIND NODES(c) AS nd // to get all the nodes on which I want to iterate
 FOREACH(n in nd|
 WITH n as start
 path = allShortestPaths((start)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]-> (p1:Category {catName:   "Main_topic_classifications"}))
 UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
 WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
 MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)

 )
```

For each node c, I try to compute all shortest paths to reach the root and than I use the returned path result to create a newrelationships (NEW_SUBCAT). However, when I run the previous query, I get the follwoing error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map or ')' (line 5, ...)
```

Comment: As for what's wrong, FOREACH operates on collections, but `nd` is not a collection (`nodes(c)` is a collection, but you used UNWIND to change this back into individual rows, so `nd` is a node, not a list of nodes)

Answer (score 0):

This simpler query may do what you want (`FOREACH` is totally unnecessary):

```
MATCH (start:Category)
WHERE ()-[:SUBJECT]->(start)
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((start)-[:SUBCAT_OF*]-> (p1:Category {catName:   "Main_topic_classifications"}))
UNWIND RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rel
WITH STARTNODE(rel) AS s, ENDNODE(rel) AS e
MERGE (s)-[:NEW_SUBCAT]->(e)
```

Comment: Probably best to move the :SUBJECT part of the pattern into the WHERE clause instead of the MATCH: `MATCH (start:Category) WHERE ()-[:SUBJECT]->(start)`, that can eliminate some unnecessary redundancy and potential cardinality issues.